# Split big zip file and combine it back as original zip file

Tags: java, spring-boot, zip

I have a requirement to split a 100mb zip file(which will be having sub folders and images) into 10 zip files(each of 10mb).Then I need to send each sliced zip files to an API (as multipart reauest), in receiver API i need to combine each of the above 10 zip files back to origin 100mb zip file.

Below is the code for slicing

```
    public static void splitZip(String zipName, String location, String NewZip) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream(location);
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(fis);
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    int currentChunkIndex = 0;
    long entrySize = 0;
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(location);
    Enumeration enumeration = zipFile.entries();
    String copDest = zipCopyDest + "\\" + NewZip + "_" + currentChunkIndex +".zip";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(copDest));
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
    long currentSize = 0; 
    try {
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null && enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getSize());
            entrySize = zipEntry.getSize();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if((currentSize + entrySize) > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                zos.close();
                currentChunkIndex++;
                zos = getOutputStream(currentChunkIndex, NewZip);
                currentSize = 0;
            }else{
                currentSize += entrySize;
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entry.getName()));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                byte[] unzippedFile = outputStream.toByteArray();
                zos.write(unzippedFile);
                unzippedFile = null;
                outputStream.close();
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        zos.close();
    }
}
```

When i extract slices zips manually i found some images are corrupted am not able to open it. **Also am not getting a proper solution for combining the zip files**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a requirement that each individual file has to be a valid ZIP file? Because otherwise just splitting the byte stream in 10 MB chunks is conceptually and code-wise much easier.

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like you need to execute the `else` part in both cases (i.e. whether you switch to a new ZIP file or not), because otherwise you basically skip every file that happens at a ZIP-file boundary.

Comment: No .. only after combining all individual zip files it should be valid.

Comment: In that case the easiest solution is probably to ignore the  fact that it's a ZIP file and just send 10MB chunks of it to the server to receive and not use an of the `Zip*` classes at all.

Comment: As per requirement i need to go with zip files only..

Answer (score 0):

Zip specification has a feature to split zip files to any desired length (minimum split length should be 64kb). [Zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j), supports this feature to create split zip files ([documentation](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#creating-a-split-zip-file)). You can then pass each split file to the api. The api can then use the [merge functionality](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#merging-split-zip-files-into-a-single-zip) in zip4j to merge those split files into a single zip file. On a side note: even without merging, it is a perfectly valid zip file. as long as all the split zip files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The approach will not work if you have any file in the zip greater than 10 mb and also the else condition should be executed in both the cases and in this approach you have to depend on the size of file in zip may be better you go with approach of not creating smaller zips